# How do I query if a commit lies between two known commits?

Tags: git

Consider the following git history:

```
* commit bfa39b2c6952295dbcfcf8b25667e1965401aed1
| Date:   Wed Aug 24 15:50:14 2016 -0700
|
|     Fix bug introduced by fb77497
|  
* commit ed3d7d82e7c6e6771e0495e3588c5c3089664883
| Date:   Wed Aug 24 15:50:09 2016 -0700
|  
* commit fb77497e8d235d142fca2e18f74895e131b59978
| Date:   Wed Aug 24 15:50:06 2016 -0700
|
|     Massive refactor
|  
* commit be56876ce707df48ca8df683d3f81a11244b9cef
  Date:   Wed Aug 24 15:50:01 2016 -0700
```

Say commit `fb77497` introduced a bug which is later fixed by `bfa39b2`. So, both `fb77497` and `ed3d7d8` are affected by this bug, but `bfa39b2` and `be56876` are not. If the history was longer, you would say that all the commits from `fb77497` (inclusive) to `bfa39b2` (exclusive) are affected.

What command can I use to determine if a specified commit lies in this range? It would also be great if the command worked intuitively with multiple branches.

Note that the bisect command does not apply here -- I already know where the bug was introduced and fixed.

Comment: What about just `git log --pretty='%H' fb77497..bfa39b2 | grep the_commit_you_are_asking_about`?

Comment: @larsks: that may find unwanted commits.  (Depending on some questions about the two specified nodes.)

Comment: How so? That would only list commits between the one introducing the bug and the one fixing it, which seems to be what you're after...

Comment: @larsks: I'm working on a longish answer with some sample graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to do this; which one to use, or which one is "most efficient", depends on other items.  The two main methods are using `--ancestry-path`, which is an option to `git rev-list` (and therefore also to `git log`), and `git merge-base --is-ancestor` (available since Git version 1.8).

So:

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path A..B
```

will produce most of what you want, except that it excludes commit *A* and includes commit *B* (see corner cases section below).  These are full hashes so you can now use `grep` to match them directly *as long as* you grep for full hashes (you don't want to have abbreviated hash `a123` match full hash `98765a123999...`).

#### Discussion

First, let's note that this is a graph problem.  We have a DAG, such as this:

```
     o--o--o--o
    /
o--o--o---o--o--o
    \    /       \
     o--o         o
                 /
o--o--o         o
```

We choose two distinct nodes *A* and *B*.  If we choose nodes that are from disconnected subgraphs, there is *no* path from *A* to *B*:

```
     o--o--o--o
    /
o--o--o---o--B--o
    \    /       \
     o--o         o
                 /
A--o--o         o
```

so the question "is any other node on some path between *A* and *B*" is moot as there is no such path.  Even without a disconnected subgraph, though, we can still hit this issue.  Consider what happens if we choose `A` and `B` this way:

```
     o--o--B--o
    /
o--o--o---o--A--o
    \    /       \
     o--o         o
                 /
                o
```

There is still no path from `A` to `B` and no path from `B` to `A`.  However, `git rev-list A..B` or `git rev-list B..A` *will* produce a list of commits, specifically those reachable from the second commit ID but not from the first.  For instance `git rev-list A..B` will list the starred commits:

```
     *--*--B--o
    /
o--o--o---o--A--o
    \    /       \
     o--o         o
                 /
                o
```

plus commit B itself.

We must therefore choose *A* and *B* such that either *A* is an ancestor of *B* or *B* is an ancestor of *A*.  (It's reasonable to constrain this with *A* != *B* as well, which we did when we said *distinct* nodes.)  Without loss of generality, we can assume *A* is an ancestor of *B*, by simply swapping *A* and *B* if not, and if appropriate:

```
     o--o--o--o
    /
o--B--o---o--A--o
    \    /       \
     o--o         o
                 /
                o
```

Here we simply swap so that *A* is the more-left commit and *B* is the one towards the right (I'm assuming history moves left to right here, so that all the arrows point leftward, or up-and-left or down-and-left, in this particular planar graph).

Now, there may be *more than one* path from *A* to *B*, so our interest is whether arbitrarily chosen node *C* lies within *any* ancestry path from *A* to *B*:

```
     o--o--o--o
    /
o--A--*---*--B--o
    \    /       \
     *--*         o
                 /
                o
```

If we choose one of the now-starred nodes for *C*, the answer is "yes, *C* is an ancestor of *B* and a descendant of *A*".  If we choose any *other* node for *C* the answer should be "no": either *C* is not an ancestor of *B* (the three nodes to the right of *B*, or any node along the top row) or *C* is not a descendant of *A* (any of the bottom row nodes, or the node to the left of *A*).

Using `git rev-list`:

```
git rev-list A..B    # or: git log --format=%H A..B
```

we will get the starred commits, plus commit *B* itself (commit *A* is omitted unless you use `--boundary`, but adding `--boundary` can get a bit tricky with complex graphs as it leaves in *all* boundary commits, including those on unwanted paths, so it's probably better to just check for *A* directly, or add it to the list).

The two drawbacks here occur in two cases: first, if *A* is *not* an ancestor of *B*, we may still get some commits!  This was our earlier example when `B` was in the top line of our graph.  But even if *A* *is* an ancestor of *B*, we may get *too many* commits:

```
     o--o--o--o
    /
o--o--A---*--B--o
    \    /       \
     *--*         o
                 /
                o
```

These three starred commits, plus *B* itself as usual, are what `git rev-list` (or `git log`) will select for a simple `A..B`: commits reachable from *B* (including *B* itself), that are not reachable from *A*.  Unfortunately that includes two commits we did not want.

One solution is to add `--ancestry-path`.  The `--ancestry-path` option constrains `git rev-list`'s output to exclude commits that are not descendants of the first commit.  Hence:

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path A..B
```

will produce just *B* itself plus the one starred commit in:

```
     o--o--o--o
    /
o--o--A---*--B--o
    \    /       \
     o--o         o
                 /
                o
```

Of course, it will also produce nothing at all if *A* is not itself an ancestor of *B* (or produce *B* alone if *A = B*).

#### Using `git merge-base --is-ancestor`

You can also test one commit at a time, using `git merge-base --is-ancestor`.  Assuming we have already put *A* and *B* into the right order:

```
if git-merge-base is-ancestor $C $B && git merge-base is-ancestor $A $C; then
    ... $C is "between" $A and $B
fi
```

As a good side effect, a commit is considered its own ancestor, so this matches if *C = A*, but you will still need to test for *C = B* to discard that case.

#### Corner cases to beware of: #1

All along here, I have been assuming that commit *A* is the one that introduces the bug and *B* is the one that fixes the bug—not quite the same as your example.  You of course just moved one node back in the graph from the fix—but if the fix occurs as a result of a merge, "moving one back" may be tricky, as there may be more than one predecessor commit.  For instance, suppose *B* is the bug-fix in a graph that goes like this:

```
...--A--o--o--B--...
      \      /
       o----o
```

Here we may want to check every node after *A*, including those on both rows, but `B^` (the first parent of *B*) may be on the top or bottom row and will exclude the other row.

(There is a trick for this using `gitrevisions` syntax, which I have not tested thoroughly:

```
git rev-list --ancestry-path ^A B^@
```

The `^@` suffix means "all parents of *B* but not *B* itself", and the `^` prefix means "use *A* as an exclusion ID", and `--ancestry-path` seems to use all exclusion IDs for the "must be descendent" constraint.  It could also be worth trying `^A^@` here to get *A* included—it seemed to work in one too-simple test I just tried.)

#### Corner cases to beware of: #2

Using `--boundary` will add commit `A` back to the list produced by `git rev-list` (marked with a leading `-`), but combining `--boundary` with `--ancestry-path` does not really work right.  The `--boundary` flag tells Git to include commits excluded by a boundary condition, but sometimes this includes non-ancestry-path boundary commits.  So it works great for commit `A` itself, but not for commits snipped away while also not being on a non-ancestry path.  It's a bit hard to come up with a quick graph example, and this one is not tested:

```
          o-----o
         /       \
...--o--A--o--o--B
      \   / \    /
       o-o---o--o
```

Here `--ancestry-path` tries to prune the unwanted part of the bottom row, but `--boundary` may put back one of the unwanted commits.  (I have seen this in action but don't remember precisely what triggers it, which is why this may be a bogus example.)